# difference with Kleen regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

just started to appreciate regex and I am practicing it on [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/lesson/7?)
my question is given the explanation about kleene "*". I came up with an answer on my own"

```
[a-c]*
```

but the solution is:

```
aa+b*c+ or a*b*c*
```

is there any differences in terms of behavior with the two? especially if I use it with javascript?

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is insufficiently defined, as there are no negative examples.

For example, if they ask you in medical school "what is the name of the device that amputates", "a car" is technically correct, but probably not what they wanted to hear (as a number of car accidents end up with people with cut off limbs). But had the question been "What is the name of the instrument a medical professional would use to perform an amputation during surgery", the answer can't be "a car" any more.

Similarly, your solution will work for all provided cases, but it is not as precise as theirs. For example, `"cba"` is recognised by your expression, but is rejected by theirs (at least not as a match of the whole string; `a*b*c*` trivially matches `"cba"` as a 0-length match anywhere in the string, and as a 1-length match of the `"a"` bit). For that matter, `.*` is also a valid (but completely imprecise) solution to their problem.

Comment: can you please give me an example somehow my solution might fail? I would appreciate it for the sake of learning :)

Comment: It can't on their examples. If they had an example where they said "it can't match an empty string", then your solution would have been wrong; but they didn't, so it isn't. It merely allows for more solutions than their solutions do. In fact they even say something similar in their third paragraph. Where did you see that "the solution is `aa+b*c+` or `a*b*c*`"?

Comment: below the textbox where you intput your solution. there's a text there saying "Solve the above task to continue on to the next lesson, or read the Solution." click the solution link

Comment: There is an infinite number of possible solutions; theirs are just some examples. Reread the page again with this in mind. You can go to the next page with any solution that gets you all three checkmarks; e.g. `c` is another pattern that matches in all three examples. (Proof for infinite number of possible solutions: `.*`, `.*a*`, `.*a*a*`, `.*a*a*a*`.... would all allow you to proceed.)

Comment: I see thanks! you answered my question and kudos to @Konstantin for giving me an idea on making more strict solution, you guys deserve an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the general regex behavior in JavaScript and in other languages. The task basically requires that you give the most restrictive regex that matches the patterns provided. They also provide an alternative answer to show that you can match the pattern with a less restrictive regex as well. The things to look for with the provided patterns are the following:

1. There are always pairs of `a`-s: `aa`, `aaaa`
2. There is 0 or more `b`-s: `b`, `bbbb`, no `b`
3. There is 1 or more `c` at the end: `cc`, `c`, `cc`
4. The letters always come in this order: `abc`

There is a lot of regex you can come up in order to match these four conditions so you would need to attempt providing the most restrictive one in order to minimize the matches outside of these examples. Still even with the provided answer you will match infinitely many other strings.

An even more restrictive regex would be:

```
^(aa)+b*c+$
```

Here the regex requires that the string starts with `aa` and ends with a `c`. I assume that the lessons still haven't gotten to `^` and `$` and thus the answer provided does not include these.

Comment: "There is no different in the `regex` behavior in `JavaScript` and in other languages"... as long as you stick to basics like Kleene star. There are certainly differences in more advanced capabilities (notably, JS does not support lookbehind, recursivity, subroutines, named captures, conditionals...)

Comment: @Amadan I meant in general and given the early enough tutorial that is provided. If the answer goes in depth explaining all the differences that can be observed between the different regex engines, then the answer will become way too long. You're right though, implementation introduces differences in the engines, but still in pure theory of computation point of view regular expressions are equivalent to finite automatons and are uniform across the board.

Comment: Yes, but what people on SO call regular expressions (and what regexone evaluates) are not theoretical regular expressions, and they aren't at all equivalent to FA any more. If we were on [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/), I would not make this comment. But your edit ("general") is all I wanted - I dislike it when people lie to learners for sake of simplicity, but as long as they say "well not really but you don't need to know details yet" it's good. Prevents all kinds of confusion when someone tries to evaluate `/(?<=a)b/` and they're like "WTF regexp is supposed to be same everywhere!"

Comment: @Amadan I agree and that's why I made the edit. Thanks for pointing it out!